# Does dotnet core have a built in JSON serializer/deserializer for console applications?

Tags: c#, json

I'm creating a console application in dotnetcore.  Do I have to get a specific package to support JSON serialization etc?

Comment: The other users have answered your question but here's a link to the docs for the new System.Text.Json . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in 3.0+, the `System.Text.Json` namespace is available for your use.

If you're targeting one of these,

- NET Standard 2.0 and later versions
- .NET Framework 4.7.2 and later versions
- .NET Core 2.0, 2.1, and 2.2

You can install the [`System.Text.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json) package.

Comment: my project says ```<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>``` but I have dotnet core 3.0.1 installed.  Can I just change the version ?

Comment: If your project is netstandard, it's probably a library. In that case, I'd recommend using the `System.Text.Json` NuGet package.

Answer (score 3):

The `System.Text.Json` and `System.Text.Json.Serialization` namespaces has support for JSON serialization/deserialization.